# Поиск по свойстсвам вложенного объекта MongoDb

Tags: json, mongodb, объекты, поиск

Есть обычная коллекция с вложенным объектом customer:

```
{
    ...
    "status" : "...",
    "segment" : "...",
    "customer" : {
        "company" : "ООО \"ААА\"",
        "name" : "Василий",
        "id" : 789,
        "email" : "vasyan@г.ru"
    },
}
```

Эти данные прилетают в виде JSON с поисковой формы, свойства могут быть заполнены в разноброс, как можно найти такой элемент, зная лишь некоторые свойства customer и свойства самого объекта?

Через точку customer.id как-то не особо подходит, больше в документации ничего не увидел, такое

```
.find({customer:{name:Вася}})
```

Требует передачи всех свойств вложенного объекта, я правильно понял?

Есть какой-то способ выполнить поиск по только известным свойствам вложенного объекта? Или придётся выносить кастомеров в отдельную коллекцию?

Comment: через точку нормально находит

Comment: Мне на бекенд приходит json, чтобы передать его в монгу через точку - его нужно будет серьёзно обработать, это извращение на мой взгляд и так делать не нужно, должны быть более удобные способы

Comment: Так в чем тогда вопрос, в том, что Вы не можете составить правильный запрос на получение данных или в том, как стилистически более удобно написать запрос?

Comment: Вопрос в удобстве, я не совсем понимаю, почему нельзя просто передать объект запроса с вложенным объектом, с массивами же так работает